# Show that $F(x(a)) - F(x(b)) = a - b$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x(t)$ be a solution of $\dot{x} = f(x)$, where $f$ is positive and periodic ( $ f(x+L) = f(x) $, $L > 0$ ). Let 
$$F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{f(\zeta)} d \zeta.$$
I want to show that
$$F(x(a)) - F(x(b)) = a - b.$$
Using the fundamental theorem of Calculus I found that:

- I know that $F(x+L) - F(x) = F(L)$, where $F(L)> 0$ is a constant.
- I know that $\frac{d}{dt} F(x(t)) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second conclusion is wrong, you have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}F(x(t))=\left.\frac{1}{f(\zeta)}\right|_{\zeta=x(t)}\dot{x}(t)=\frac{1}{f(x(t))}\dot{x}(t)=\frac{1}{\dot{x}(t)}\dot{x}(t)=1
$$
so 
$$
F(x(t))=t+c\implies F(x(a))-F(x(b))=(a+c)-(b+c)=a-b
$$